# Gradle project refresh failed - Cause: invalid stream header: FFFFFFFF

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Criei um projeto novo no Android Studio. Entretanto, ao abrir, aparece o seguinte erro:

```
Error:Cause: invalid stream header: FFFFFFFF
```

[image: Erro em questão - imagem]

Como poderei resolver esta situação?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provavelmente seus arquivos do gradle corromperam. Tente esses passos:

1) File -> Invalidate Cache

2) Delete a pasta `.gradle` do seu projeto

3) Dê um rebuild no projeto